# How to store a movieID in variable

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to store my `movieID` as a variable but I am struggling to find out how to :

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
    movieID=$('.movieContainer').attr("movieID");
    console.log(movieID);
});
```

I want to be able to pull the `movieID` so I have multiple movies and if I want to edit it I can do it with the `movieID` so it matches the index number of my array. I am pretty noob and have tried looking around but havent found anything yet :S

```js
for (var i = 0; i < movieEntries.length; i++) {
  var title = movieEntries[i][0];
  var content = movieEntries[i][1];
  var date = movieEntries[i][2];
  var movieID = i;

  var movieEdit = '<div class="movieContainer" movieID="' + movieID + '">' +
    '<div class="movieTitle"><input type="text" value="' + title + '"></div>' +
    '<div class="movieContent"><input type="text" value="' + content + '"></div>' +
    '<div class="movieDate"><input type="text" value="' + date + '"></div>' +
    '<input type="button" value="edit" class="edit">' +
    '<input type="button" value="delete" class="delete">' +
    '</div>' + '<br><br><br>'

  $("#mainContainer").append(movieEdit);
}
```

Comment: We have to see your HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `this` keyword to target the related `movieContainer` like :

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
    movieID=$(this).closest('.movieContainer').attr("movieID");
    console.log(movieID);
});
```

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var title = 'title';
  var content = 'content';
  var date = 'date';
  var movieID = i;

  var movieEdit = '<div class="movieContainer" movieID="' + movieID + '">' +
    '<div class="movieTitle"><input type="text" value="' + title + '"></div>' +
    '<div class="movieContent"><input type="text" value="' + content + '"></div>' +
    '<div class="movieDate"><input type="text" value="' + date + '"></div>' +
    '<input type="button" value="edit" class="edit">' +
    '<input type="button" value="delete" class="delete">' +
    '</div>' + '<br><br><br>';

  $("#mainContainer").append(movieEdit);
}

$(".delete").click(function() {
  movieID = $(this).closest('.movieContainer').attr("movieID");
  console.log(movieID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mainContainer"></div>
```

Comment: sorry for being dumb but how would i then make the corresponding index=null with the movieID as the way to know which has being interracted with

Comment: No worries bro, just try to describe what you want exactly with more details so I could understand well your final desired result.

Comment: I want to delete the movie post so when i delete it deletes the index so the movieEntries index will get deleted according to which movieID i clicked the delete button on

Comment: Try to use `delete movieEntries[movieID]` that will leave the index of deleted item _empty_.

Comment: I tried but failed again.... https://gyazo.com/b307011ea67ef8b4c253f0165c84afad it deletes all my posts :SSS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184712/discussion-between-noobprogrammer1337-and-zakaria-acharki).